# Java and csv Data

Tags: java, csv

Hello I want to use 10 Csv files in my Java Program. Are there any options to build relations between the individual Csv files ? 
For example if I have a csv file with postal codes and another one with postal code and Names of the cities how can I connect these two ?
And what are packages/classes I can work with csv in Java ?
Thanks for your answers !

Comment: Is there any effort from your side?

Answer (score 0):

There are much ways to approach your problem.

for example you could store the information of a csv file into an `ArrayList`. Afterwards check if the other CSV files contains the inforamtion stored in your `Arraylist`. That is done by iterating through your list and using the `contains()` method to check for similar information.

```
ArrayList<String> cityNames; //I assume you stored information in this list

for(String aCity : cityNames){
           if(aCity.contains(aCityNameFromOtherCSV)){
           int indexOnSameEntry = aCity.getIndex()  //and now you have the index were your information on the lists are the same
       }
    }
```

But there is no basic way to answere your question. Your question is to broad and not specific at all. Please narror you question on what you really want to to with the data of your files and also what you already tryed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [csvjdbc](http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/) and use a few SQL statements to join the "tables". That should make your life easier.